# How do I get MSMQ message count from a private queue on local Win7 machine?

Tags: c#, windows-7, msmq

I am trying to get a count of MSMQ messages from a private queue on a local Win7 Enterprise machine.  I can get the count from a remote machine without problem and the code works on Win2008 Server R2.  I am using C# VS 2008.

Code sample:

```
int result = MQMgmtGetInfo(cname, "queue=DIRECT=OS:" + qname, ref props);
```

where `cname` is the machine name with private queue, `MyLocalComputer`, and
`qname` is the path reference to the private queue, `MyLocalComputer\\private$\\QueueName`

When I call this code from the Win7 computer containing the private queue I get a `-1072824319` return value.  There are messages in the queue.

If I call this code from a WinXP computer to get counts on the Win7 queue, I get correct counts.  I can also call the code from a WinXP computer to get counts from a local private queue on the same WinXP machine and get correct counts.

Is there something different about accessing local private queues on Win7?  Since I can access the queue remotely I wouldn't think it is a permissions issue, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Here's what I found that seems to work. If the cname variable used by MQMgmtGetInfo refers to the local machine, this variable must = null when passed to MQMgmtGetInfo. I added a function to check for local machine and set cname accordingly.

Comment: you should answer your own question and accept that answer.  It was very helpful, but I didn't see your comment until after I ran down two other rabit holes.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are using the MSMQ 3.0 API. Windows 7 uses MSMQ 4.0.

In the .NET references window look for *System.Messaging* (version 4.0.0.0) and add to your project.

Take a look in this link: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/mgpmyqueue.aspx

[]'s

Renan

Comment: The version of MSMQ shouldn't matter - one version of MSMQ should support all the APIs from older versions.

Comment: Version list of MSMQ by OS: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2007/03/14/how-do-i-install-msmq-4-0-on-my-windows-2003-server.aspx

Answer (score 1):

-1072824319 = 0xC00E0001 which is a generic MSMQ error.
Try using a full stop instead of the machine name.
 
That will tell MSMQ to use "local host".
If that works then there may be a problem with the machine resolving it's own name.

Cheers
John Breakwell

Comment: Thanks, John.  This particular code runs in a DLL used by another program of mine.  I am using the machine name because I don't know where the MSMQ I will be accessing will be installed - remotely or locally.  Now, since it works on WinXP and not Win7, I think I need to request elevated permissions for my DLL with an app.manifest. Does that sound right?  I'll give it a try.

Comment: Sure - the full stop was just a troubleshooting suggestion.

Comment: I don't know about whether requesting elevated permissions will help - worth a try.